# Highlight row based in streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, styling, streamlit

I can't seem to find any specific answers to my question as I'm not sure if it can be done with `apply` or `applymap`.

I have a parameter dataframe, lets call it `x`. I have a raw data frame, lets call it `y`.

```
  y = pd.DataFrame({"a": {"h":0.5,"x": 2, "y": 1}, "b": {"h":15,"x": 20, "y": 6}})
  x = pd.DataFrame({"thres1": {"x": 2, "h": 1,"y":3}, "thres2": {"x": 10, "h": 12,"y":3}})
```

`x` provides the thresholds where if certain column of raw data exceeds, will require the row to be highlighted. Note the rows in `y` needs to be compared to the correct rows in `x` given the row indexes. There can be situations where `x` will have more rows than `y`, (but not the other way around, so we need to make sure we `.loc` to match the correct row.

so for example, I want to compare column "b" in raw dataframe `y` to column 'thres2" in raw dataframe `x`. for the first row of `y` in column "b", its 15. I need to compare 15 to the second row second column of `x` which is 12. Because its bigger, I need to highlight that.

`apply` apply the entire dataframe while `applymap` does cell by cell. Issue is I need to do .loc before. How would styling the dataframe work for this in streamlit? (preferably without json please)

Update: I'm trying to get the row index "B" to highlight but it doesn't. Here is an example app that tries to do this:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def MainDashboard():
    st.sidebar.title("Test")

    df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], index=["A", "B"])
    def color_b(s):
        return np.where(s == "B", "background-color: yellow;", "")
    df.style.apply_index(color_b)
    st.dataframe(df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainDashboard()
```

[image]

Comment: Example directly from pandas docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply_index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Styler.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) with `axis=None` for pass entire DataFrame, for compare need same columns and index labels, so rename `x.columns` by [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html):

```
import streamlit as st

highlight_greater = lambda z: pd.DataFrame(np.where(z.gt(x.set_axis(z.columns, axis=1)),
                                          'background-color:red',
                                           ''), index=z.index, columns=z.columns)
styled = y.style.apply(highlight_greater, axis=None)

st.table(styled)
```

IIUC use:

```
highlight_greater = lambda z: np.where(y.gt(x.set_axis(z.columns, axis=1)).any(axis=1), 
                                       'background-color:red', '')
df.style.apply_index(highlight_greater)
```

Comment: a follow up question: instead of changing the entire row color how can i just change the dataframe row index color?

Comment: @user1234440 - Add to answer, but not tested. Can you try?

Comment: i've tried everything but i can't seem to get it to work. I even tried something similar to the documentation. The dataframe index just wont display the highlighted index on streamlit for some reasons.

Comment: i've added full example st app, are you able to replicate the issue?

Comment: @user1234440 you need reassign like `styled = df.style.apply_index(color_b)` and `st.dataframe(styled)`